# Convergence of $\sum_{i\ge 1} (e^{(-1)^i\sin (\frac{1}{i})}-1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that the series $$\sum_{i\ge 1} (e^{(-1)^i\sin (\frac{1}{i})}-1)$$ converges .

I was thinking about applying the alternating series test. Letting $c_i$ be the general term, I need to show that $|c_1|\ge |c_2|\ge \dots$; the series is alternating, and $c_i\to 0$.

I think monotonicity holds because $e^x, 1/x$ are monotonically increasing on $(0, +\infty)$ and $\sin x$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,1]$.

It is alternating because $r_i=\sin(1/i)\in(0,1]$ so $e^{r_i}\in(1,e]$ and $e^{-r_i}\in[1/e,1)$. So $c_{2i}$ are positive and $c_{2i-1}$ are negative.

Is the above correct? How can I show that $c_i\to 0$?

Comment: Actually as I read my question I think I need to say more to establish monotonicity. Because there is $(-1)^i$ inside the $\exp$...

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Taylor expansion gives
$$e^{(-1)^i\sin(1/i)}-1=(-1)^i\sin(1/i)+\frac{\sin^2(1/i)}{2}\Bigl(1+\epsilon(i)\Bigr)=u_i+v_i$$

it is a sum of an alternating convergent series $\sum u_i$ and a series whose general term $v_i$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2i^2}$ which converges.

their sum is then convergent.

Comment: Why did you use this form of the second form on the RHS (the one with $1+\epsilon_i$) instead of say $O(x^2)$?

Comment: @user5579085 to use limit comparison test.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use the limit comparison test. I'd write $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$ and then the original series is $\sum ((-1)^i\sin(1/i)+O(\sin^2(1/i))$. If I write them as the sum of two series, the first series is convergent by the test I menioned in the question, and the second is convergent by the usual comparison $|O(\sin^2(1/i))|\le C|\sin^2(1/i)| < C/i^2$. Can I do this? (I'm not sure about whether I can write the series as the sum of two series and investigate their convergence separately and also not sure whether the above estimate is correct (I'm not very familiar with O notation).)